# Amazon Ami - Error "instaling nokogiri using bundle"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems, nokogiri

If I execute:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
```

The installation occurs successfully.

When I execute:

```
 bundle install --deployment
```

I get:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
extension.

    /home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby extconf.rb  Extracting libxml2-2.8.0.tar.gz into
tmp/x86_64-amazon-linux/ports/libxml2/2.8.0... OK Running 'configure'
for libxml2 2.8.0... ERROR, review
'tmp/x86_64-amazon-linux/ports/libxml2/2.8.0/configure.log' to see
what happened.
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
options.

Provided configuration options:     --with-opt-dir  --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include  --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib  --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog     --srcdir=.  --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484/bin/ruby
/mnt/sdh/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:265:in
`block in execute': Failed to complete configure task (RuntimeError)
from /mnt/sdh/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `chdir' 
from /mnt/sdh/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:257:in `execute' 
from /mnt/sdh/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:65:in `configure' 
from /mnt/sdh/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/mini_portile-0.5.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:108:in `cook' 
from extconf.rb:101:in `block in <main>' 
from extconf.rb:119:in `call' 
from extconf.rb:119:in `block in <main>'
from extconf.rb:109:in `tap' 
from extconf.rb:109:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /mnt/sdh/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for
inspection. Results logged to /mnt/sdh/beta/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.1), and Bundler
cannot continue. Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'`
succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Have you tested that you have the same version of Ruby and Rails that you are expecting?

Issue
    `ruby -v` and `rails -v` to check

Comment: Thanks 

I don't know what happened, but I'm run rvm use 1.9.3@linkia and it's works

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem with libxml2 `for libxml2 2.8.0`

Try to install patch so nokogiri can use :

`sudo yum install -y patch`

Then, install nokogiri:

`sudo gem install nokogiri`

I found this answer on [AWS Developer Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=152406) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My application was in /mnt/sdh

My fstab file was /dev/sdh /mnt/sdh defaults,user 0 0

I just remove the 'user' flag from fstab then it runs successfuly